# Do plants originate from a single cell

Tags: cell-biology, botany, reproduction, life, seeds

I read the generalization that life originates from a cell, and from my understanding animals, they originate from a single cell, produced as a result of sexual reproduction. And then life begins to develop from there on. But when it comes to botany, I stumble upon this doubt because of plant seed varieties. During any stage of seed production, can the seed be designated as having come from a single cell. Can i use the following generalization and correct me wherever i am wrong.

```
every life is made of cells, and every life comes from a single cell
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for how to ask questions and what we expect here. In particular this site values questions that show some attempt at answering themselves. So, what do you know about spermatogenesis and oogenesis in plants and fertilization?

Comment: nice of you for helping me with the terms, i will look up and get back. So my question is supposedly looked down upon as being vague, and ill-researched ?

Comment: In a nutshell, that's correct. The [homework help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) section states: *What is a homework question?... ... A question that addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals" among other things.  You might also want to look into plant cloning and things like coppicing and stolons and compare to sexual reproduction.

Comment: Obviously a plant has to come from a single cell, because cells can only multiply by division, so at one point there must have been a single cell. In plants the germ cell is called an "ovule" and it is a single cell.

Comment: Or, as [Rudolph Virchow](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2603088/) famously put it in the 19th century: _omnis cellula e cellula_ (“every cell stems from another cell”).

Comment: plant single cell phase is caled plant gametes.

Answer (score -1):

You are actually right by saying that. The embryo of a seed is a single cell that germinates after several cell division and differentiation resulting in to a whole plant.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. At SE we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a two-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Otherwise how can the poster or anyone else know whether or not you are correct? See the Help for ["how do I write a good answer?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In addition, to what David pointed out your answer is misleading. Most plant embryos consist of many cells and germination is often (if not usually) triggered by environmental factors and has no direct connection to cell division.  ——— NB:From "How do I write a good [answer]?" in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* Please delete this post as it is both inadequate and encourages the posting of questions that are not appropriate for this site — please see the [tour] and other [help] pages such as [ask] and [answer] for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Bro, most life on earth start drom a single celled condition called the zygote. And it is applicable to most plants also ( I say "most" because biology is full of exceptions and pretty much most of the time, we can generalize ).

Comment: Welcome Adithya. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance, you'll find that we need answers. to be supported by references and citations, you can improve your answer by [edit]ing those in.